# Как дозаписать в файл с помощью WriteFile

Tags: c++, winapi

Я написал код для дозаписи строки в файл

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA("C:\\Users\\user\\file.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0,0);
    std::string str = "TEXT";
    DWORD bytess;
    DWORD toWrite = str.size();
    LPCVOID n = "\n";
    SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, 0, FILE_END);
    WriteFile(hFile, n, toWrite, &bytess, 0);
    WriteFile(hFile, str.c_str(), toWrite, &bytess, 0);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

Но файл выглядит следующим образом

```
    TEXT
```

Почему в нём присутствует табуляция, и как я могу совершить дозапись в файл без подобных проблем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рассмотрим поподробнее аргументы функции `WriteFile`:

1. `HANDLE hFile` – хэндл открытого файла
2. `LPCVOID lpBuffer` – буфер, из которого брать данные для записи
3. `DWORD nNumberOfBytesToWrite` – количество байтов, которые нужно записать
4. `LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesWritten` – количество байтов, которые фактически были записаны
5. `LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped` – ещё один спец. параметр, нам он здесь не интересен

Теперь посмотрим на Ваш вызов функции:

```cpp
WriteFile(hFile, n, toWrite, &bytess, 0);
```

И рассмотрим два аргумента:

`n` – указатель на ОДИН символ

`toWrite` – длина строки `"TEXT"`, равная ЧЕТЫРЁМ

Ответ напрашивается сам собой: Вы даёте функции один символ, а записать просите 4. Результат налицо: т.к. Вы передаёте указатель, границ функция не видит, а потому без проблем вписывает Ваш символ и ещё 3 байта, стоящих в памяти за ним, отображающихся в файле как пустые символы.

В доказательство можно открыть полученный файл чуть более продвинутым редактором, чем Блокнот:

[image: отображение в Notepad++]

В результате видим, что перед текстом действительно не символ табуляции, а перевод строки и три пустых символа – `NUL`.

Отсюда решение: если уж Вы пишете один символ, то передайте в соответствующем аргументе 1:

```cpp
WriteFile(hFile, n, 1, &bytess, 0);
```